# Is there a native word in Japanese that refers to "to have intercourse with" with high fidelity?

Tags: words, verbs

I realized that after learning Japanese for so many years I still don't know what the word is in Japanese that has the meaning "to have intercourse with" specifically.

Therefore, I am looking for a Japanese verb meaning "to have intercourse with" that:

1. is not 外来語　e.g.　セックスする;
2. is not 漢語 e.g. 性交する;
3. means "to have intercourse with" explicitly, not through euphemism;
4. is not slang;
5. refers to "to have intercourse with" with high fidelity (not like e.g. やる);
6. should better be a 他動詞　s.t. it can fill in "A は　B を　_____.";

Point 5 is important, by which I mean the verb should not have other meanings, like "肏" in Chinese, "씹하다" in Korean and "fuck" in English(?). Though I am not a native English speaker and I know "fuck" as a verb has many meanings, I feel like "to have intercourse with" is still the main and genuine meaning and other meanings seem to have derived from this. Although "fuck" might mean something else before it acquired the meaning of "have intercourse with", this must have happened before people started to use the verb "fuck" in other ways (as in "to fuck around", "fuck it!" etc.) .

In comparison, やる, which is the answer many Japanese people told me after I asked them this question, seems to have too many meanings (to do, to kill, to complete, etc.).

Comment: (I really did not get it when I found that this question had received four downvotes literally seconds after I posted the question. To those who did it: did you downvote just because you found the title dirty without even taking a look at the description? I am serious about this question.)

Comment: I did not downvote, but I think you have to be more specific. You're basically asking us to look up words. Plus, I don't think people will want to look up words related to "fuck".

Comment: The question was flagged automatically because of the content. The users who can do something about this [have been notified](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59326104); otherwise, moderators can cancel the flags and the implied downvotes.

Comment: If the Japanese word you're looking for is not a swear word, I don't see how "fuck" would be an appropriate comparison. Why not just say you're looking for a word that explicitly means "to have sexual intercourse." Even "fuck" is not that straightforward. It has like a dozen meanings and uses. It's unlikely any other language has a word exactly like it. I didn't downvote, but I can see why, in light of what I mentioned, the question comes across as someone just wanting to say "fuck" a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Leebo . I just edited the description a little bit. Actually, my point is, if Japanese were to have a word like "fuck", then this word would have become a swear word in daily conversation. Since Japanese people use くそ and other expressions to swear, I guess that (modern) Japanese might lack a word that can be equivalent to "fuck" in English.

Comment: FSY, I agree with Leebo's comment; if you don't say #3 (from your question) in English then it's probably going to be a euphemism. --- EG: In Chinese, "約炮 - 这周好想约炮啊", I have big artillery or let's make an appointment (asap). If you don't explain it like a doctor (or Spock) then it's probably about being unclear.

Answer (score 6):

I also believe the word *fuck* has too many meaning too, but...

There's a word for it: [まぐわう](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%90%E3%82%8F%E3%81%86).

[This](https://renso-ruigo.com/word/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%90%E3%82%8F%E3%81%86) dictionary even has "ファックする"(To fuck).

It's a word that we don't see much anymore (because we have ヤる, セックスする, etc...), but I think it will be understood by most people. ...Maybe.

Comment: Very interesting, a much better match than my attempts! JMdict has a notice “from 目合ひ”.

Comment: Thank you! I just looked up まぐわう(媾う/目合う), it seems that it is a quite loyal word for "to have intercourse with". However, it might fall short a little bit in the aspect that it is not a 他動詞.

Comment: @FSY  Well, then, as far as I know there's no other words that can satisfy you. By the way, how did you thought that this is "loyal" word?

Comment: @Skye-AT By "loyal" I mean with relatively high fidelity. The dictionary just gives one meaning of "媾う".

Answer (score 4):

So, the question is a bit awkwardly phrased and the emphasis on “fuck” is a bit over the top, but I did try to find a native Japanese word for “to have sexual intercourse”.

As you may know, native Japanese words are commonly called 大和言葉 (Yamato kotoba), so I searched for “性交する　大和言葉” and came across [this page](https://joshi-spa.jp/236726) which reviews a book “Speaking Yamato Japanese beautifully” and cites some examples.

As the expression for セックス／エッチ it gives 「契りを結ぶ」and by looking it up I discovered that 契{ちぎ}る [does have such a meaning](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%A5%91%E3%82%8B). Although it’s only a secondary one, I suspect it will be understood correctly with proper context (the dictionary gives an example 男と契る).

I guess that’s probably the closest you can get without further euphemisms, but I think it will sound strange and awkward in modern setting (similar to many other Yamato words).

P.S. Following the cross references, it seems まじわり can also mean “sexual intercourse” (as in 夫婦のまじわり), however the verb itself (交わる) is more neutral and does not imply sex by default.

Comment: I think that is a quite close one. Though 契る originally means to bind (an agreement with), I have never seen 契る used in that way. 契る may fall short a little bit since it is a 自動詞 (as is まぐわう). It really seems that Japanese does not have a word ≈ f**k, even an obsolete one.